# Разные спряжения для "стелить" и "постелить"

Tags: глаголы, спряжение, морфология

Почему *стелить* относится к 1-му спряжению, а *постелить* ко 2-му? Выходит, что пишется *ты стел**е**шь* и *ты постел**и**шь*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

А почему  вы решили, что глаголы "постелить" и "стелить" разного спряжения? Приставка спряжения не меняет! Так что "стелешь" и "постелешь".

Answer (score 1):

Вы что-то не поняли.
Возможно, речь шла о том, что разные спряжения у глаголов "стелить" и "стлать". Но при этом первый имеет неполную собственную парадигму и пользуется большинством личных форм второго (т.е. всеми, кроме прошедшего времени). Отсюда и 1-й тип спряжения глагола "стелить".

А приставка, как уже сказали, совершенно не влияет на его тип.